# Create empty space between pasted range

Tags: vba, excel

I am doing the filter then copy/paste data from a workbook to other. I am able to handle the filter and copy/paste. But I don't know how to create empty space if a product code have more than two order. I attached the picture for easier understanding.
My code execution:
[image]

And I want it turn to this:
[image]

Here is my code:

```
Sub Order()
Dim I As Double
Dim strKeyWord As String
Dim myCount As Integer
Dim checkEmpty As Range
Dim N As Long

Dim SubTotal As Range, Country As Range, DisCount As Range, RequiredData As Range

Dim wsOrder As Worksheet
Dim wsCondition As Worksheet
Dim wbOrder As Workbook
Dim wbCondition As Workbook

Dim OrderFile As String
Dim ConditionFile As String

'Open Order wb
OrderFile = Application.GetOpenFilename()
Set wbOrder = Workbooks.Open(OrderFile)
Set wsOrder = wbOrder.Worksheets(1)

'Open Condition wb
ConditionFile = Application.GetOpenFilename()
Set wbCondition = Workbooks.Open(ConditionFile)
Set wsCondition = wbCondition.Worksheets(1)

With wsCondition
    .Range("B1").Value = "Product code"
    .Range("C1").Value = "Order Condition"
    .Range("D1").Value = "Subtotal"
    .Range("E1").Value = "Discount"
    .Range("F1").Value = "Country"
End With

'using the CountA ws function (all non-blanks)
myCount = Application.CountA(wsCondition.Range("A:A"))

For I = 2 To myCount Step 1
    strKeyWord = wsCondition.Range("A" & I)
    wsOrder.Range("R:R").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=*" & strKeyWord & "*"
    'lRow1 = WorksheetFunction.Max(wsOrder.Range("I65536").End(xlUp).Row)
    If wsOrder.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row > 1 Then
        Set SubTotal = wsOrder.Range("I2", wsOrder.Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        Set Country = wsOrder.Range("AG2", wsOrder.Range("AG" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        Set DisCount = wsOrder.Range("N2", wsOrder.Range("N" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        Set RequiredData = Union(SubTotal, Country, DisCount)
        RequiredData.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
        With wsCondition
            .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = strKeyWord
            .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = "Availabe"
            .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial
        End With
    Else
        With wsCondition
            .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = strKeyWord
            .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = "no Order"
            .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = "N/A"
            .Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = "N/A"
            .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = "N/A"

        End With
    End If
Next I
End Sub
```

Thank you for your help :D

Comment: and what's wrong with your code? Are you getting an error? where?  If you're not sure where the problem is, you coudl try usign [F8] to step through the code.  Here's more about [**Debugging VBA**](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx).

Comment: Hello, thanks for your time. My code is fine. The point is I want to create the empty line for a product code which have more than 1 order. You can check my attached pictures for better understanding :D

Comment: What does the source data look like? From the pics you provided it is not obvious why the empty line belongs to H7